# Software Center install button not working

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center, deb

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I'm getting very frustrated.

When clicking the "install" button to install a .deb package, it does absolute nothing. I click it more than once, and still, nothing.

I've even tried installing the .deb file through terminal:

```
sudo apt install <package name>.deb
```

and get:

```
> E: Unable to locate package code_1.13.1-1497464373_amd64.deb E:
> Couldn't find any package by glob 'code_1.13.1-1497464373_amd64.deb'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex
> 'code_1.13.1-1497464373_amd64.deb'
```

Someone please help before I pull my hair out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong command in terminal.

You have to use `sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE`.

Replace `DEB_PACKAGE` by your `packagename.deb`. Your `*.deb` should be in `$HOME` folderfor the above command to work. Otherwise, use full pathname.

For details see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line).

***Other Way***

You can also install a deb file by double clicking it using `gdebi`.
Install it by command `sudo apt-get install gdebi` and then open the `*.deb` file by double clicking using *open with* gdebi.